# Servlet not returning json response

Tags: json, servlets, httpresponse

I am running a forwarding proxy that returns json response from a remote server to the client.
For certain requests where the json body returned is quite large the response body is not returning. The server responds aptly with the json response but the proxy is unable to return the response.

This is the piece of code I am using to write back the response

```
      try
        {
            InputStream _respStream = _httpMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();

            String _respBody = getStringFromInputStream(_respStream);
            logger.info("response body::\n"+_respBody);

            _out  = _response.getWriter();

            JSONObject _jsonObj = new JSONObject(_respBody);
            logger.info("json object::\n"+_jsonObj);
            _out.print(_jsonObj);
                            //_out.print(_respBody);
            logger.info("json returned in response");
            //_out.flush();
            _out.close();
            logger.info("FINISHED");
        }
        catch(IOException _ioe)
        {
            logger.error("error in writing back the response body", _ioe);
        }
```

P.S. I also tried copying the inputstream directly to the servlet outputstream but even that didn't work.

Comment: Did you checked if the proxy is getting the json properly? Just a thought?

Comment: yes, the proxy is receiving apt json response from the server. Its been logged.

Comment: Ok. From the above code I am not able to find anything. But just a suggestion, you can use Firefox browser and a tool like firebug/httpfox to check the request and response. Might help you to find out something, if something is wrong there

Comment: Actually I am able to workaround the problem, actually I was copying all response headers from the server to the HttpServletResponse of the proxy that included 'Transfer-Encoding' chunked, which somehow was not supported in both chrome/firefox while I got the response using curl. For now I am skipping the header but the strange thing is it does send response with the same header if I directly hit the server instead of proxy. can somebody explain that?